# Why is chattr and lsattr resulting in "Operation not supported while reading flags"?

Tags: symbolic-link

I'm getting the following error:

```
$ lsattr /etc/rc.local 
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /etc/rc.local

$ sudo chattr +i /etc/rc.local 
chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 19):

I did not notice it at the time, but the error was occuring because the file is a symlink:

```
$ ls -l /etc/rc.local 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 13 Feb 16  2012 /etc/rc.local -> rc.d/rc.local
```

Strangely, lsattr on CentOS 5 works on symlinks.

Comment: If you didn't notice this when you wrote the question, why did you put it in the tag?

Comment: In the event that it's not obvious to those unfamiliar with such systems, given the example above, the `chattr` operation should be performed on the symlink's *target*, and not the symlink itself: `sudo chattr +i rc.d/rc.local`.

Comment: Interesting - so we can protect the directory, but not a symlink. My use case would be to also prevent the symlink from being changed, but it seems we can not do this?

Comment: I've always vaguely wondered what this was. Thanks.